# record audio + video stream into a file with the "tee" command with gstreamer 1.0

Tags: audio, video, stream, gstreamer, record

I'm trying to record a specific audio + video-stream to a file (while this stream is displayed on the same machine).
Here is the code from my receiver.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# A simple RTP receiver
#
#  receives H264 encoded RTP video on port 5000, RTCP is received on  port 5001.
#  the receiver RTCP reports are sent to port 5005
#  receives alaw encoded RTP audio on port 5002, RTCP is received on  port 5003.
#  the receiver RTCP reports are sent to port 5007
#
#             .-------.      .----------.     .---------.   .-------.   .-----------.
#  RTP        |udpsrc |      | rtpbin   |     |h264depay|   |h264dec|   |xvimagesink|
#  port=5000  |      src->recv_rtp recv_rtp->sink     src->sink   src->sink         |
#             '-------'      |          |     '---------'   '-------'   '-----------'
#                            |          |
#                            |          |     .-------.
#                            |          |     |udpsink|  RTCP
#                            |    send_rtcp->sink     | port=5005
#             .-------.      |          |     '-------' sync=false
#  RTCP       |udpsrc |      |          |               async=false
#  port=5001  |     src->recv_rtcp      |
#             '-------'      |          |
#                            |          |
#             .-------.      |          |     .---------.   .-------.   .-------------.
#  RTP        |udpsrc |      | rtpbin   |     |pcmadepay|   |alawdec|   |autoaudiosink|
#  port=5002  |      src->recv_rtp recv_rtp->sink     src->sink   src->sink           |
#             '-------'      |          |     '---------'   '-------'   '-------------'
#                            |          |
#                            |          |     .-------.
#                            |          |     |udpsink|  RTCP
#                            |    send_rtcp->sink     | port=5007
#             .-------.      |          |     '-------' sync=false
#  RTCP       |udpsrc |      |          |               async=false
#  port=5003  |     src->recv_rtcp      |
#             '-------'      '----------'

# the destination machine to send RTCP to. This is the address of the sender and
# is used to send back the RTCP reports of this receiver. If the data is sent
# from another machine, change this address.
DEST=192.168.1.1

# this adjusts the latency in the receiver
LATENCY=200

# the caps of the sender RTP stream. This is usually negotiated out of band with
# SDP or RTSP. normally these caps will also include SPS and PPS but we don't
# have a mechanism to get this from the sender with a -launch line.
VIDEO_CAPS="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264"
AUDIO_CAPS="application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio,clock-rate=(int)8000,encoding-name=(string)PCMA"

VIDEO_DEC="rtph264depay ! avdec_h264"
AUDIO_DEC="rtppcmadepay ! alawdec"

VIDEO_SINK="videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=720,height=480 ! autovideosink"
AUDIO_SINK="audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink"

gst-launch-1.0 -v rtpbin name=rtpbin latency=$LATENCY                                  \
     udpsrc caps=$VIDEO_CAPS port=5000 ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_0                       \
       rtpbin. ! $VIDEO_DEC ! $VIDEO_SINK                                             \
     udpsrc port=5001 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0                                       \
         rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5005 host=$DEST sync=false async=false\
     udpsrc caps=$AUDIO_CAPS port=5002 ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_1                       \
       rtpbin. ! $AUDIO_DEC ! $AUDIO_SINK                                             \
     udpsrc port=5003 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_1                                       \
         rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_1 ! udpsink port=5007 host=$DEST sync=false async=false
```

I've found a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796152/record-video-from-a-video-using-gstreamer-1-0) how to record instead of playing a video stream but my intention is to play video + audio and record both to one file (for example mp4 or mkv).

In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364610/gstreamer-tee-multiple-multiplexer) i red that i have to do this by using the queue, tee and mux commands but i need some help by adding them correctly.

My thoughts were adding the commands like this :

```
...
VIDEO_DEC="rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! tee name=videoTee"
AUDIO_DEC="rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! tee name=audioTee"

VIDEO_SINK="videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=720,height=480 ! autovideosink !"
AUDIO_SINK="audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink"

gst-launch-1.0 -v rtpbin name=rtpbin latency=$LATENCY                                  \
     udpsrc caps=$VIDEO_CAPS port=5000 ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_0                       \
       rtpbin. ! $VIDEO_DEC ! $VIDEO_SINK                                             \
     udpsrc port=5001 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0                                       \
         rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5005 host=$DEST sync=false async=false\
     udpsrc caps=$AUDIO_CAPS port=5002 ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_1                       \
       rtpbin. ! $AUDIO_DEC ! $AUDIO_SINK                                             \
     udpsrc port=5003 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_1                                       \
         rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_1 ! udpsink port=5007 host=$DEST sync=false async=false \
                   matroskamux name=mkvMux ! filesink location=test1.mkv \
                    videoTee. ! queue ! mkvMux. \
                    audioTee. ! queue ! mkvMux.
```

but i get following error:

*WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link autovideosink0 to udpsrc1*

probably i have to change the position of these commands or/and i missed something.

It would be great, if i would get some hints to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some professional help solving my problem.
here's the correct way:

```
VIDEO_DEC="rtph264depay ! tee name=video_splitter ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264"
AUDIO_DEC="rtppcmadepay ! tee name=audio_splitter ! queue ! alawdec"

...

rtpbin. ! $AUDIO_DEC ! $AUDIO_SINK\
udpsrc port=5003 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_1\
rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_1 ! udpsink port=5007 host=$DEST sync=false async=false \           
matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location=test.mkv \
video_splitter. ! queue ! h264parse ! mux.video_%u \
audio_splitter. ! queue ! mux.audio_%u
```